# How can I get a Canon CanoScan 4400F Scanner working in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, canon, scanner

I was looking at a Canon CanoScan 4400F Scanner, however Canon does not appear to offer a driver for Linux

Is there any other way to get this device to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you already own this device? If yes and you just plug it in and use the program simple scan (standard application on ubuntu), doesn't it work? Because most scanners and printers should work. All I've ever owned work, and also the printing system is the same as on apple's macOS X.

Answer (score 2):

According to Ubuntu Wiki the CanoScan 4400F is not recognized by xsane. listed as unsupported in sane-device-database.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon

There is one try at creating a driver:
http://sane.10972.n7.nabble.com/Canoscan-4400F-driver-update-td5319.html